# How to render contents of a tag in unicode in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, xml, web-applications, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a soup from a WordPress post detail page:

```
content = soup.body.find('div', id=re.compile('post'))
title = content.h2.extract()
item['title'] = unicode(title.string)
item['content'] = u''.join(map(unicode, content.contents))
```

I want to omit the enclosing `div` tag when assigning `item['content']`. Is there any way to render all the child tags of a tag in unicode? Something like:

```
item['content'] = content.contents.__unicode__()
```

that will give me a single unicode string instead of a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
unicode(content)
```

It converts `content`'s markup to a single Unicode string.

Edit: If you don't want the enclosing tag, try:

```
content.renderContents()
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to omit the enclosing tag. Outer DIV in this case.

Comment: well, renderContents() return a str and not a unicode. I would like to avoid unnecessary encoding & decoding.

Comment: I checked the docs and the source code, but I couldn't find a method that returns the contents as a single Unicode object. renderContents() returns a string encoded in UTF-8. So converting the result of renderContents() to a Unicode object is the best approach I can find.

Comment: Yes, unicode/renderContents combo certainly beats my map/unicode combo.

Comment: I think it's only fair this answer is accepted. I remember I wasn't able to change it then.

Comment: On Python3 you can use `str(content, 'utf-8')` to convert the UFT-8 bytestring to unicode